# Springboot MongoRepository findAll() method returns an empty list, But other Methods return valid results

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, rest, spring-data

`findAll()` method of mongoRepository returns an empty list. what is wrong with the below code?
API used for counting the number of documents in the collection works fine and because of that, `findAll()` also should return a valid result.

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/api-management/scopes")
public class AuthScopesController {
    private final ScopesService scopesService;

    @Autowired
    AuthScopesController(ScopesService scopesService) {
        this.scopesService = scopesService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    public AuthScope createScope(@RequestBody AuthScope authScope) {
        return scopesService.createAuthScope(authScope);
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public List<AuthScope> getAllScopes() {
        return scopesService.getAuthScopes();
    }
}
```

service

```
@Service
public class ScopesService {

    private final AuthScopeRepository authScopeRepository;

    public ScopesService(AuthScopeRepository authScopeRepository) {
        this.authScopeRepository = authScopeRepository;
    }

    public AuthScope createAuthScope(AuthScope authScope) {
        return authScopeRepository.save(authScope);
    }
    //TODO: recheck
    public List<AuthScope> getAuthScopes() {
        return authScopeRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

repository

```
@Repository
public interface AuthScopeRepository extends MongoRepository<AuthScope, String> {
    Optional<AuthScope> findByScope(String id);
}
```

model is as follows

```
@Data
@Document("auth-scopes")
public class AuthScope  {
    @Id
    private String scope;
    private String belongsToApi;
    private String belongsToApiTitle;
    private String description;
}
```

Comment: Empty list means there is no data in the collection.

Comment: there are data in the collection. api to get the number of documents in the collection works fine.

Comment: What code is used for counting?

Comment: can you check connection details as well if they are correct

Comment: public int getAuthScopesCount() {
        return  (int) authScopeRepository.count();
  } 
this works fine. so connections details cannot be incorrect

Comment: named queries also working

Answer (score 0):

found the issue. in order to findAll() to work, the model has to have deleted status.

I've updated the model as follows

```
@Data
@Document("auth-scopes")
public class AuthScope  {
    @Id
    private String scope;
    private String belongsToApi;
    private String belongsToApiTitle;
    private String description;
    private boolean deleted;

}
```